# How merge duplicate object and add price

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database

How merge duplicate object and add price like it has tree dublicate then price will add up three time and return new array/obj. this is obj here [obj](https://snack.expo.io/@mgonekar/ludicrous-cake). and also keep track how many duplicates are there

```
"id1": Object {
  "date": 1609247265357,
  "orders": Array [
    Object {
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/jsa/128.jpg",
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Tomato",
      "price": 15,
    },
    Object { //this
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/talhaconcepts/128.jpg",
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Ginger",
      "price": 12,
    },
    Object { //and this
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/talhaconcepts/128.jpg",
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Ginger",
      "price": 12,
    },
    Object {
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/jsa/128.jpg",
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Tusi",
      "price": 15,
    },
  ],
  "uid": "EKSjIptE7Ma32SyGylhKBmLLJHB2",
},......and so on
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet? It's much more likely someone can and will help you if we see what you've tried already.

Comment: I search stackoverflow but havnt found problem like this. Tried uniqby but dont know how to go deep as key Id changes. and keep track how many times dublicate removed so we can multiply price.